# Current UTC Timestamp not able to get it

Tags: pyspark

current_utc_timestamp() function to get the current utc time but its giving error as not defined and

I have imported all functions and tried still its giving issue

can anyone please help me in this to get current UTC Time

thanks

Comment: Could you provide some example code of where you're using this function? So others can try to reproduce it (see: [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a very straightforward approach:
Import the from_utc_timestamp() function from the
pyspark.sql.functions module, Call the current_timestamp() function
to get the current timestamp in the local timezone and then Pass the current
timestamp to the from_utc_timestamp() function to convert it to UTC.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp, current_timestamp

# Get the current timestamp in the local timezone.
current_timestamp_local = current_timestamp()

# Convert the current timestamp to UTC.
current_timestamp_utc = from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp_local)

# Print the current UTC time.
print(current_timestamp_utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Get the timezone of the machine on which the code will run and use it to convert `current_timestamp()` to UTC timestamp as given below.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from graphframes import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()


simpleData1 = [
(1, 'firstname1', 'lastname1', 'address1', -97),
(2, 'firstname1', 'lastname1', 'address1', -23),
(3, 'firstname2', 'lastname2', 'address2', -23),
(4, 'firstname2', 'lastname2', 'address2', -97)
]
columns = ["id","name", "last", "address", "bookID"]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(simpleData1).toDF(*columns)

df1.show()

timezonenow = str(datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo)
print(timezonenow)



df1 = df1.withColumn("utc_timestamp", to_utc_timestamp( current_timestamp(), lit(timezonenow)))

print("With UTC timestamp value")
df1.show()
```

Output :

```
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
| id|      name|     last| address|bookID|
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+
|  1|firstname1|lastname1|address1|   -97|
|  2|firstname1|lastname1|address1|   -23|
|  3|firstname2|lastname2|address2|   -23|
|  4|firstname2|lastname2|address2|   -97|
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+

IST
With UTC timestamp value
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+-----------------------+
|id |name      |last     |address |bookID|utc_timestamp          |
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+-----------------------+
|1  |firstname1|lastname1|address1|-97   |2023-10-09 14:32:08.211|
|2  |firstname1|lastname1|address1|-23   |2023-10-09 14:32:08.211|
|3  |firstname2|lastname2|address2|-23   |2023-10-09 14:32:08.211|
|4  |firstname2|lastname2|address2|-97   |2023-10-09 14:32:08.211|
+---+----------+---------+--------+------+-----------------------+
```